# `pip install` failing with "Permission denied" in a virtualenv

Tags: macos, unix, permissions, python, pip

I'm currently using pip + virtualenv to isolate the Python dependencies in my Django application. It's worked alright so far, and I've been able to install a bunch of packages in the past. But when a coworker added the oauth2 dependency for django-social-auth I tried installing it from the updated env_reqs file using `pip install -r env_reqs` and received the following error:

```
error: could not delete '/Users/jeremypress/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tests/__init__.py': Permission denied
```

Thinking it was, perhaps, an issue with the env_reqs file, I also tried `pip install oauth2` only to receive the same error. `chown`ing and `chmod`ing the file didn't help either...

I hesitate to just run `sudo pip install oauth2` because I think the `sudo` bypasses the virtualenv and installs the package globally.

To clarify, I'm running OSX. Any ideas or explanations?

Answer (score 2):

Have you activated your virtual environment?

Run:

```
. bin/activate
```

in your shell. Then the local `pip` installation will take over the system one.

If that also does not work try running:

```
~/.virtualenvs/myapp/bin/pip install -r oauth2
```

Instead of just:

```
pip install -r oauth2
```